# SSRS Error : Could not connect to server, ( since the TLS 1.0 was disabled)

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Since the recent patch where TLS 1.0 was disabled and 1.1, 1.2 Enabled , we are having issues where the SSRS in the server cannot make connections to the Database server.

[image]

We had to re-enable TLS1.0 to make the connection successful. Is there something that can avoid enabling it as it was identified to be a vulnerability.
What needs to be done to make it work with TLS 1.2?

Comment: I suspect your firewall either isn't allowing TLS 1.1/1.2 traffic or isn't able to.  Check with your Network Admin to make sure these SSL settings are allowed with the current firewall configuration.

Comment: Checked semms its not a firewall issue but no luck. Googled around and found this : This issue occurs because SSMS, Report Manager, and Reporting Services Configuration Manager use ADO.NET, and ADO.NET support for TLS 1.2 is available only in the .NET Framework 4.6. For earlier versions of the .NET Framework, you have to apply a Windows update so that ADO.NET can support TLS 1.2 communications for the client...... Seems we will have to apply a window patch to have the SSRS running with TSL 1.2